# Fastest way to check what file should be deleted

Tags: c#, delete-file

In the response from server I can find paths to images on server. So I download them by paths to my local folder.

As this response is not the same every time, I don't want to have unused images in local folder, so I want to remove them.

But what way will be the fastest?

- Delete all images and then download all used images?
- Download only not existing images first and then check which saved images are unused?

Or maybe, there are other options?

Thanks

---

**UPD**

I have model `ImageDTO`

```
public class ImageDTO
    {
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        public string FileLocation { get; set; }
    }
```

And Method to save Image to local Folder

```
private static void SaveImageByUrl(string relativeUrl)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(relativeUrl))
            {
                var localFilePath = new Uri(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + relativeUrl).LocalPath;
                if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(localFilePath)))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(localFilePath));
                }
                if (!File.Exists(localFilePath))
                {
                    var remoteFilePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteUri"] + relativeUrl;
                    using (var client = new WebClient())
                    {
                        client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(remoteFilePath), localFilePath);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Property `FileLocation` contains relative path to Image.

From server I get response in `Json` format. I deserialize it into Collection of Objects, clear local Database and save them into local Database(I also have `ProductDTO` which contains `List<ImageDTO>`. So really i receive response of `List<ProductDTO>`). While I am doing that I asynchronosly save Images to local Folder.

So would be better to clear all images from local folder while I am clearing data from Database or check if I have image that doesn't come from response and delete it?

Comment: This question seems off-topic but since you explicitly asked for other options... Does rsync meet your requirements? https://rsync.samba.org/

Comment: @rsync - I don't want any 3rdparty components.

Comment: Your question is very broad and I cannot answer it without a lot more context. That is probably why it got downvoted. It would help if you could make the question more specific. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to improve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only download the images you need and delete the once that you don't need.
This will be faster than downloading all images, certainly if images tend to be the same and if you're working with a large amount of images.

You can also enhance your code by only deleting images if they haven't been used for x times

Comment: `Only download the images you need and delete the once that you don't need.` this is logicaly :) But i don't know what image is useless and what is faster - download image or check if i need it? this is what I want to check)

Comment: " only download what you need " requires you to know beforehand what you need. So you need to check it. Maybe you can first request a list of all the filenames. Compare this list with what you already have and then request all the files with a name that you don't have yet.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your response is a list of source image paths, you are then creating a local copy using some logic for building a local path?

If that is the case, reverse the logic so you can determine what the original path should be from the local.

Then iterate over the local images and figure out what the source image would have been. If that isn't in the response, delete the file.

So if your logic is to take the file name and extension but in a different directory, you can reverse that.

Then carry on downloading new and updated images. You decide if your source images are going to change - if they don't then just download the new ones. Otherwise you'll need to update images too. It depends on what you want. You could assume images over x days should be replaced or do a file byte count to see if they differ.